# Shelosha Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeravam (the first king of the Ten Tribes, a brilliant Torah scholar but a wicked person) knew how to explain each concept in the Book of Vayikra in 103 different ways.

(Appropriately enough, this statement appears in the Gemara Sanhedrin on page **103** b.)

Comment: That's a slam dunk, Alex!

Comment: Checkmark for slam dunk. "Shelosha umeya - peirushei malka."

Answer (score 4):

The last two dynasties that governed Israel prior to the Second Temple's destruction maintained their rule for 103 years (Avodah Zara 9a): The Chashmonaim from 140 BCE to 36 BCE, and the Herodians from 36 BCE to 68 CE.

Comment: Honorable mention for being an honorable mench. Your answer's pretty good, too.

Answer (score 0):

Off to the west of the main Altar's ramp stood a silver table upon which the *Kohanim* would set out the ninety-three vessels used in the daily service. These ninety-three vessels were actually three sets of thirty-one vessels, since the Temple kept on hand two backup copies of each of its vessels in case one should become *tamei* or otherwise unusable. The following is a list of the thirty-one vessels (as recorded in the *sefer Ezras Kohanim*):

1. *Issaron* measuring cup (for dry goods)
2. Half-*issaron* measuring cup (for dry goods)
3. Half-*hin* measuring cup (for liquid goods)
4. Third-*hin* measuring cup (for liquid goods)
5. Quarter-*hin* measuring cup (for liquid goods)
6. *Lug* measuring cup (for liquid goods)
7. Half-*lug* measuring cup (for liquid goods)
8. Quarter-*lug* measuring cup (for liquid goods)
9. Slaughtering knife
10. Meat knife
11. Knife for trimming fat
12. Cleaver
13. *Mizrak*, a cone-shaped vessel for receiving the blood of sacrifices
14. Golden cup used to water the lamb for the *Tamid*-offering prior to its slaughter
15. *Teni*, a golden basket used to collect ashes from the Golden Altar
16. *Kuz*, a cup to collect unused oil from the *Menorah*
17. *Bezach*, a large, golden spoon used to bring innards to the Altar
18. Golden spoon of the Incense
19. Cover for the Incense spoon
20. *Bezach* for the Incense
21. Silver *machatah*, a shovel used in the Incense service to collect coals from the Outer Altar
22. Golden *machatah*, a shovel to carry the coals (transferred from the silver shovel) into the Sanctuary
23. *Pesachter*, a large, multipurpose container
24. *Magrephah*, a shovel-like vessel designed to make a loud clatter when dropped
25. Bowl for mixing *Minchah*-offerings
26. Bowl to hold the oil for *Minchah*-offerings
27. *Machavas*, frying pan for certain *Minchah*-offerings
28. *Marcheshes*, pot for certain *Minchah*-offerings
29. *Mazleig*, tool for adjusting the wicks of the *Menorah*
30. *Machatah*, tool for cleaning the lamps of the *Menorah*
31. *Alas*, a ladle for transferring liquids”

See **The Original Second Temple** by Yoav Elan.

In addition to these 93 utensils were ten vessels:

- The *Menorah* – *chesed*;
- The Table – *gevurah*;
- The Altar - *tiferet* with its connection to *malchut*;
- The Basin and Jug or Laver - *netzach* and *hod*;
- The Ark – *bina*;
- The Curtain – *chochmah*;
- The cherubs on the Ark – *keter*; &
- All in its Weight/*shekel* – *malchut*.

See ***Likkutei Sichos***, Vol. XXI, *Vayakhel-Pekudei*.

Thus it would appear that there is a total of 103 vessels and utensils in the Temple.

Answer (score 0):

David said one hundred and three chapters, and he did not say Halleluya in any of them until he saw the downfall of the wicked. [(Berachos 9b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.9b.29?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi)

Answer (score -1):

Mincha = 103

Avimelech = 103

Nechama = 103